# How to update 404 page meta tag in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using yoast plugin for seo for the blog wordpress in my site
by default plugin assigns below meta tag for 404 page

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>
```

I want to update this meta tag to the below one

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
```

I have gone through yoast plugin documentation 
But didn't find any solution 
Can this be done using yoast plugin itself or Is thee any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `header.php` file for your WordPress theme you can use the below code which uses the [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) ,   [is_404](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) to check if it is 404 page and prints out the `meta` tag which you wish for. So use the options from yoast plugin wherever you need and if you want to change it for specific pages then you can use the conditional tags.

```
<?php if(is_404()): ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The above solution assumes that Yoast Plugin is not adding any meta tags to header. But if Yoast adds it's own meta tags then you can try the below solution

Add the code to `functions.php` file

```
add_filter('wpseo_robots', 'yoast_no_home_noindex', 999);
function yoast_no_home_noindex($string= "") {
    if (is_404()) {
        $string= "noindex,nofollow";
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: But now i can see two meta tag in my 404 page,

how to remove yoast meta tag for 404page

Comment: Oh. So yoast is adding the meta tags already. So, Please check the updated answer for another solution. May be that will help.

Comment: Thanks for reply 
May i know where should i add that code ?

Comment: In functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

In `frontend/class-frontend.php` of the plugin directory, change the following

```
if ( is_search() || is_404() ) {
                $robots['index'] = 'noindex';
            }
```

into

```
if ( is_search() || is_404() ) {
            $robots['index'] = 'noindex';
            $robots['follow'] = 'nofollow';
        }
```